# Rest API Post Request Returns '403 Forbidden'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, json, choice-field

I am trying to create a new choice (radio buttons) field using REST API request in my SharePoint Online environment and this is the code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mysubsite/_api/contextinfo",
method: "POST",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success:function(data){
    var digest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mysubsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyListName')/fields",
        type: "POST",
        data: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldChoice' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 6, 'Title': 'NewChoiceField', 'Choices': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 'results': [ 'Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3' ] }, 'EditFormat': 1 },
        headers: { 
            "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(digest),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(){console.log("success");},
        error: function(){console.log("error");}
    });
},
error:function(data){
    console.log("error getting the digest value")
}
});
```

However, I get '403 Forbidden' as a response.

The `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException` thrown is

> "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

Any ideas?

P.S. The account has definitely got the required permissions.

Comment: Modify the request digest header as `"X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val` and check. If its in the same web, you dont need `contextInfo` value via AJAX call

Comment: @GautamSheth `$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()` is undefined in modern SharePoint pages, hence the first request to get the digest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use the `FormDigestValue` in the `RequestDigest` header in Modern pages.

The `__REQUESTDIGEST` is a hidden HTML element which is not present in modern pages. So, it had tripped up your code.

Have modify your code as below by adding the payload separately and then stringifying it:

```
var payload = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldChoice' }, 
              'FieldTypeKind': 6, 'Title': 'NewChoiceField', 'Choices': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 'results': [ 'Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3' ] }, 'EditFormat': 1 
            };

$.ajax({
url: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mysubsite/_api/contextinfo",
method: "POST",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success:function(data){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mysubsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyListName')/fields",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: { 
            "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(){console.log("success");},
        error: function(){console.log("error");}
    });
},
error:function(data){
    console.log("error getting the digest value")
}
});
```

Comment: any luck the above code ? i tried it in my Modern page environment and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addChoiceField(){
    var siteUrl="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mysubsite";
    var listTitle="MyListName";
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl+"/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success:function(data){
            var digest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
            $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+listTitle+"')/fields",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldChoice' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 6, 'Title': 'NewChoiceField', 'Choices': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 'results': [ 'Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3' ] }, 'EditFormat': 1 }),
                headers: { 
                    "X-RequestDigest": digest,
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function(){console.log("success");},
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log("error getting the digest value")
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="AddField" onclick="addChoiceField()"/>
```

[image]